# Opening encrypted file without decrypting physically

Tags: vb.net

I have developed Digital Library using vb.net, storing all files(PDF,MS-Officefiles and images) by encrypting, user searches files and open while opening I have to decrypt and open, now i don't want to decrypt file in the drive, can I open file by decrypting in the memory? please help to solve this problem,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: unless you are also developing the viewers of those files, you can't just de-crypt the file and display them.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is **yes you could**. You could decrypt a file and not store its decrypted version in the file system, but keep it in memory to display it or do it whatever you want.

You could use this [this encryption/decryption tutorial](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_crypt_file.html) as your base and alter the code so that it does not save the unencrypted content in a `FileStream` but in another `Stream`. Of course, you would have to use as a decrypting algorithm, the one you used to encrypt the file.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Glad to help. If you found my reply useful, you should upvote it. It is critical for users navigating to your question, to be able to see the useful answers as soon as possible.